# How to know where is the driver for a device ?

Tags: drivers

Lets say I have a mice device and I can see the touch events from **/dev/input.mice** but I was thinking where is the driver.

Answer (score 0):

usually drivers come in the form of kernel modules. these are stored under `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>`. you can find out what your `<kernel-version>` is using:

```
uname -r
```

as an example, you can find the modules directory like so:

```
echo "Modules directory: /lib/modules/$(uname -r)"
```

and then `cd` to it with `cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)`. the modules are separated into their respective folders, however some modules are built into the kernel itself, and I'm guessing generic drivers such as mice drivers and keyboard ones would be built in.

I'm not 100% sure this answers your question as it seems you may want to find a mouse driver which doesn't "exist" as such if you're looking for it as a physical file, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Info on the driver used is normally in the kernel messages available on `dmesg` and normally available in the file `/var/log/syslog` and the relative rotated files (the old ones renamed and compressed as `syslog.2.gz` etc...).

For example, let's insert a wireless mouse in my system. At the end of the syslog I can find:

```
Oct 22 14:00:43 pern kernel: [100418.211599] usb 2-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
Oct 22 14:00:44 pern kernel: [100418.307225] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52f
Oct 22 14:00:44 pern kernel: [100418.307233] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Oct 22 14:00:44 pern kernel: [100418.307237] usb 2-1.6: Product: USB Receiver
Oct 22 14:00:44 pern kernel: [100418.307240] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: Logitech
Oct 22 14:00:44 pern kernel: [100418.309876] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/0003:046D:C52F.0004/input/input16
Oct 22 14:00:44 pern kernel: [100418.310216] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52F.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input0
Oct 22 14:00:44 pern kernel: [100418.313053] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.1/0003:046D:C52F.0005/input/input17
Oct 22 14:00:44 pern kernel: [100418.367972] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52F.0005: input,hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input1
Oct 22 14:00:44 pern mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6"
Oct 22 14:00:44 pern mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 4 was not an MTP device
```

...we have a new device, which is managed by the "input" layer, and more specifically by the "hid-generic" driver (there are two devices because there is the wireless receiver and the mouse proper).

You can go to the linux sources and find it; `hid-generic` for example is in http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/hid/hid-generic.c, which seems a stub for the basic implementation in http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/hid/hid-core.c (**note** this is a link to the Linus Torvalds kernel --- not the one is really using Ubuntu --- shouldn't be difficult to find it).

Once compiled, it will ends into the kernel (if compiled "into" it) or more normally as a module, under the directory `/lib/modules/your-kernel-version-here/...` etc. For example, in my system, I have it in `/lib/modules/3.19.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-generic.ko`.